# How can I get the length of the name of each MySQL database?

Tags: java, mysql, output, maxlength

I am trying to mimic the output of `show databases;` using java. I want to output something exactly or very similar to this:

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| test               |
+--------------------+
```

My first idea was to figure out the maximum length of all the databases names before I can start printing the output. However, I am not sure how I can do that.

I tried `select max(length(show databases));` which is not valid syntax. I did find that I can `use` all the tables and run `select length(database());` to find the length of the name, but I believe that is not what mysql does to output the results.

Is there another approach to printing the output? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SHOW DATABASES` is a *standalone* command and cannot be used as argument as you did it.

With this command you get the information you need:

```
SELECT MAX(LENGTH(SCHEMA_NAME)) FROM information_schema.schemata;
```

See also [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/schemata-table.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to query the information schema table directly. Try this

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT(table_schema), length(table_schema) from 
information_schema.tables;

+--------------------+----------------------+
| table_schema       | length(table_schema) |
+--------------------+----------------------+
| information_schema |                   18 |
| json               |                    4 |
| mysql              |                    5 |
| performance_schema |                   18 |
| sys                |                    3 |
+--------------------+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```